# How to fill color to entire div in a fixed header and place the text in the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header with a row elements (`col-xs-2`) filling it through out. I'm trying to fill the color for one `col-xs-2` element and bring the text to center. But it is instead filling only `col-xs-2` div. Can some one help me how can I do this?

[image]

ABOUT, B1, LEVEL1 etc are each one col-xs-2 elements.

[image]

I need the ABOUT div to fill completely instead of only half and bring the text to center.

My code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top text-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-class="page=='about'?'active':''"  ng-click="changePage('about')" class="col-xs-2 active">ABOUT</div>
                <div ng-class="page=='b1'?'active':''"  ng-click="changePage('b1')" class="col-xs-2">B1</div>
                <div ng-class="page=='level1'?'active':''"  ng-click="changePage('level1')" class="col-xs-2">LEVEL 1</div>
                <div ng-class="page=='level3'?'active':''" ng-click="changePage('level3')" class="col-xs-2">LEVEL 3</div>
                <div ng-class="page=='level5'?'active':''" ng-click="changePage('level5')" class="col-xs-2">LEVEL 5</div>
                <div ng-class="page=='level16'?'active':''" ng-click="changePage('level16')" class="col-xs-2">LEVEL 16</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div ng-if="page == 'about'" ng-include="'./html/about/about.html'"></div>
                <div ng-if="page == 'b1'" ng-include="'./html/about/b1.html'"></div>
                <div ng-if="page == 'level1'" ng-include="'./html/about/level1.html'"></div>
                <div ng-if="page == 'level3'" ng-include="'./html/about/level3.html'"></div>
                <div ng-if="page == 'level5'" ng-include="'./html/about/level5.html'"></div>
                <div ng-if="page == 'level16'" ng-include="'./html/about/level16.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Main.css

```
/*Header*/
.navbar-fixed-top{
  background: #EBE9DB;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .active{
  background: #1AA0DE;
  color: white;
}
```

Current Output:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The columns have a standard padding defined. You could define a style class for the divs in your css.

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0;
}
```

and add them in your HTML like so:

```
<div ng-class="page=='about'?'active':''"  ng-click="changePage('about')" class="col-xs-2 active nopadding">ABOUT</div>
```

and this for each div.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this question like this. I added the div height as the min height and solved it.

```
<div ng-class="page=='about'?'active':''"  ng-click="changePage('about')" class="col-xs-2 active nopadding">ABOUT</div>
```

and css

```
.padding{
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```